# Using a variable for an array element in shell script

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I need to setup an array and use that to loop through and list the files. I started with this setup and it works.

```
file = (x1 x2 x3 x4 x5)
for var in ${file[@]}; do
    echo $var
done
```

I have a requirement to add the timestamp on these variables, I tried a few ways and none of the seem to work. Here is one way I tried to define the array:

```
today=$(date +"%Y%m%d")
file = (x1_"$today" x2_"$today" x3_"$today" x4_"$today" x5_"$today")
```

What would be the best way to define the array, where the array element has a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're using `"$today"` is correct, no problem there.

Don't put spaces around the equal sign. It needs to be `file=(...)` in both cases. Spaces are not allowed in assignments.

You can use [Shell Check](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to catch these kinds of errors. Here's what it prints:

```
file = (x1_"$today" x2_"$today" x3_"$today" x4_"$today" x5_"$today")
     ^-- SC2283: Remove spaces around = to assign (or use [ ] to compare, or quote '=' if literal).
       ^-- SC1036: '(' is invalid here. Did you forget to escape it?
       ^-- SC1088: Parsing stopped here. Invalid use of parentheses?
```